# Can't set an alarm manager

Tags: android, kotlin, alarmmanager

What's wrong with the code since it doesn't trigger the notification (never)?
This really should work since I'm sending the corresponding information through a broadcast receiver.

The application is real simple, just one activity.

My compileSdk=33, minSdk=26, targetSdk=33.

I'm testing the app in a real device running Android 10.

This is my MainActivity.kt:

```
package com.example.firstalarmmanager

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.app.AlarmManager
import android.app.AlertDialog
import android.app.Notification
import android.app.NotificationChannel
import android.app.NotificationManager
import android.app.PendingIntent
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import com.example.firstalarmmanager.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import java.util.Calendar
import java.util.Date

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding : ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        createNotificationChannel()
        binding.submitButton.setOnClickListener { scheduleNotification() }
    }

    @SuppressLint("ScheduleExactAlarm")
    private fun scheduleNotification()
    {
        val intent = Intent(applicationContext, Notification::class.java)
        val title = binding.titleET.text.toString()
        val message = binding.messageET.text.toString()
        intent.putExtra(titleExtra, title)
        intent.putExtra(messageExtra, message)

        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            applicationContext,
            notificationID,
            intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE or PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        )

        val alarmManager = getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
        val time = getTime()
        alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(
            AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            time,
            pendingIntent
        )
        showAlert(time, title, message)
    }

    private fun showAlert(time: Long, title: String, message: String)
    {
        val date = Date(time)
        val dateFormat = android.text.format.DateFormat.getLongDateFormat(applicationContext)
        val timeFormat = android.text.format.DateFormat.getTimeFormat(applicationContext)

        AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Notification Scheduled")
            .setMessage(
                "Title: " + title +
                        "\nMessage: " + message +
                        "\nAt: " + dateFormat.format(date) + " " + timeFormat.format(date))
            .setPositiveButton("Okay"){_,_ ->}
            .show()
    }

    private fun getTime(): Long
    {
        val minute = binding.timePicker.minute
        val hour = binding.timePicker.hour
        val day = binding.datePicker.dayOfMonth
        val month = binding.datePicker.month
        val year = binding.datePicker.year

        val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        calendar.set(year, month, day, hour, minute)
        return calendar.timeInMillis
    }

    private fun createNotificationChannel()
    {
        val name = "Notif Channel"
        val desc = "A Description of the Channel"
        val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
        val channel = NotificationChannel(channelID, name, importance)
        channel.description = desc
        val notificationManager = getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }
}
```

And this is my Notification.kt:

```
package com.example.firstalarmmanager

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.app.AlarmManager
import android.app.AlertDialog
import android.app.Notification
import android.app.NotificationChannel
import android.app.NotificationManager
import android.app.PendingIntent
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import com.example.firstalarmmanager.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import java.util.Calendar
import java.util.Date

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding : ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        createNotificationChannel()
        binding.submitButton.setOnClickListener { scheduleNotification() }
    }

    @SuppressLint("ScheduleExactAlarm")
    private fun scheduleNotification()
    {
        val intent = Intent(applicationContext, Notification::class.java)
        val title = binding.titleET.text.toString()
        val message = binding.messageET.text.toString()
        intent.putExtra(titleExtra, title)
        intent.putExtra(messageExtra, message)

        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            applicationContext,
            notificationID,
            intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE or PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        )

        val alarmManager = getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
        val time = getTime()
        alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(
            AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            time,
            pendingIntent
        )
        showAlert(time, title, message)
    }

    private fun showAlert(time: Long, title: String, message: String)
    {
        val date = Date(time)
        val dateFormat = android.text.format.DateFormat.getLongDateFormat(applicationContext)
        val timeFormat = android.text.format.DateFormat.getTimeFormat(applicationContext)

        AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Notification Scheduled")
            .setMessage(
                "Title: " + title +
                        "\nMessage: " + message +
                        "\nAt: " + dateFormat.format(date) + " " + timeFormat.format(date))
            .setPositiveButton("Okay"){_,_ ->}
            .show()
    }

    private fun getTime(): Long
    {
        val minute = binding.timePicker.minute
        val hour = binding.timePicker.hour
        val day = binding.datePicker.dayOfMonth
        val month = binding.datePicker.month
        val year = binding.datePicker.year

        val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        calendar.set(year, month, day, hour, minute)
        return calendar.timeInMillis
    }

    private fun createNotificationChannel()
    {
        val name = "Notif Channel"
        val desc = "A Description of the Channel"
        val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
        val channel = NotificationChannel(channelID, name, importance)
        channel.description = desc
        val notificationManager = getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }
}
```

Comment: I similar issues before, try enabling "auto-start" in app settings on the device and see if it fixes the issue

Comment: oh and check the permissions declared in manfest, e.g. POST_NOTIFICATIONS, SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM, USE_EXACT_ALARM, RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED